# Copying cell value using Instr

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy the cell containing a string of text. I am locating the cell using the instr but not able to copy the content. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand the question, please try to explain again. Are you trying to save the string to a variable?

Comment: Monika, post your code and let us know what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

When you find the cell (using whatever method, I'm guessing you're looping through cells and using InStr to test their contents) you can assign that value to a new variable, rather than "copying" it to the clipboard.

```
Public Sub FindTheText()
    Dim strCellValue As String
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Loop through cells on a sheet to find the text "theText"
    For i = 1 To 100
        If InStr(1, "theText", Cells(i, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            strCellValue = Cells(i, 1).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Then you could use the string variable strCellValue somewhere else, or assign it to the value of another cell using:

```
Cells(2,5).value = strCellValue
```